# Solutions without #, Root objects

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following polynomial:

`poly=x^2 y - (1/(13947137604 m^3))y^4 (22728668688/s^2 - (702464 s^14)/a[3]^8 + (42239232 s^10)/a[3]^6 + (20575296 s^8)/a[3]^5 - (990448560 s^6)/a[3]^4 - (824796432 s^4)/a[3]^3 + (8758147680 s^2)/a[3]^2 + 16917361353/a[3] - (400980206115 a[3])/s^4 + (41841412812 a[3]^2)/s^6 + (282429536481 a[3]^3)/s^8 + (1129718145924 a[3]^4)/s^10)`

And I want to set the `Coeficient[poly, y^4]=0`. I did this using `sol = Solve[Coefficient[d51, y^4] == 0, Reals, Assumptions -> {s != 0, m != 0}] // FullSimplify`. However, the solution is full of `#`:

`{{a[3] -> ConditionalExpression[Root[-702464 s^24 + 42239232 s^20 #1^2 + 20575296 s^18 #1^3 - 990448560 s^16 #1^4 - 824796432 s^14 #1^5 +8758147680 s^12 #1^6 + 16917361353 s^10 #1^7 +22728668688 s^8 #1^8 - 400980206115 s^6 #1^9 +41841412812 s^4 #1^10 + 282429536481 s^2 #1^11 + 1129718145924 #1^12 &, 1], m != 0 && s != 0]}, {a[3] -> ConditionalExpression[Root[-702464 s^24 + 42239232 s^20 #1^2 + 20575296 s^18 #1^3 - 990448560 s^16 #1^4 - 824796432 s^14 #1^5 +8758147680 s^12 #1^6 + 16917361353 s^10 #1^7 +22728668688 s^8 #1^8 - 400980206115 s^6 #1^9 +41841412812 s^4 #1^10 + 282429536481 s^2 #1^11 + 1129718145924 #1^12 &, 2], m != 0 && s != 0]}}`

To remove the `#` I tried the command `ToRadical` but Mathematica still produces an answer with the `#`. Since I need to plug `a[3]` in another equation, how can I get rid of the `#` in the answer?

Comment: Is this what you want: ``Solve[Coefficient[poly, y^4] == 0, a[3], Reals] // ToRadicals // N``? It returns ``{{a[3.] -> -0.186342 s^2}, {a[3.] -> 0.529073 s^2}}``

Comment: @Domen - Rather than using `// N` which damages the index of `a[3]`, I recommend ` /. r_Root :> N[r]`

Comment: @User0212 - `Root` expressions can be plugged into other expressions, e.g., `Coefficient[poly, y^4] /. sol // Simplify` evaluates to `{0, 0}` and verifies the result.

Comment: @BobHanlon I used the `/. r_Root :> N[r]` but it didn't produce any different result from what I was getting, but you're right, it would be interesting to not mess with the index of `a[3]`.

Comment: @Domen I think your suggestion gives me what I was trying to obtain. Let me see how it works on my calculations. Thanks!